# How to use "moving" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: british-english, sentence-starts, ing

"Moving to an iphone from a normal phone is easy."

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We are not a free proofreading service or writers' workshop; for a better understanding of how to phrase questions so that they are answerable in our format, please take the site [tour] and review the [help]. Specifically, questions should be presented so that they will be helpful to future visitors. Do *you* think the sentence is correct or not? What rule or guideline or pattern leads you to think it might be otherwise?

Comment: Actually i am a little new to this setup thank you for helping me

Comment: Your sentence is fine. The gerund-participial clause "Moving to an iphone from a normal phone" is the subject and "easy" functions as predicative complement of "be" in its ascriptive sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ing form of verbs are present participle. The gerund looks exactly the same as a present participle, but it is useful to understand the difference between the two. The gerund always has the same function as a noun (although it looks like a verb). In the above example, moving is gerund.

Answer to your question is yes.

Comment: "Moving" is a verb.

Comment: Gerunds are words that are formed with verbs but act as nouns. For example:

Comment: Swimming in the ocean has been Sharon’s passion since she was five years old.

Comment: The important point is that "moving" and "swimming" are verbs not nouns. They head their respective clauses

Comment: These are verbs but used as noun. See a quick trick is to remember present participle as a verb demands auxiliary but as a gerund it don't.

Comment: It's important to grasp the difference between verbs and nouns. Just because "moving" and "swimming" are part of the subject (where nouns often occur) does not make them nouns - they are verbs. Don't call them nouns, okay?